# $X$ a connected space ; if all continuous functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ are uniformly continuous, then X is a compact

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be a subset of a normed vector space. $X$ is also a connected space. Show that if all continuous functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ are uniformly continuous, then X is a compact.

Need some help ; thank you :-)

Comment: Show first that $X$ must be separable.

Comment: Then use a metric compactification. I don't see the relevance of connectedness.

Comment: @Henno: Without connectedness, the claim is false, as can be seen by considering $X = \Bbb {N}\subset \Bbb {R} $. I am not sure that the claim is correct if you have connectedness.

Comment: I think you can conclude that $X$ is totally bounded in any uniform space. But then?

Comment: I think $X$ only needs to be a metric space without isolated points. If such a space is not compact, we can pick a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of distinct points with no cluster point in $X$. For every $a_n$ we can find a $b_n$ such that $0 < 4d(a_n, b_n) < d(a_n, a_m)$ whenever $m \neq n$. If I am not mistaken the closed balls $B[a_n, d(a_n, b_n)]$ together with $X \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B(a_n, d(a_n, b_n))$ form a locally finite closed cover. This should allow us to define a continuous function with $a_n = 1, b_n = 0$ for every $n$.

Comment: I meant $f(a_n) = 1, f(b_n) = 0$ of course. I forgot to mention that we can additionally require that $d(a_n, b_n) < 1/n$, so that $f(a_n) = 1, f(b_n) = 0$ is inconsistent with uniform continuity.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Continuous real-valued functions on the long line are uniformly continuous with respect to any compatible uniformity. If anything useful can be proved for general uniform spaces, my first guess would be pseudocompactness.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen the long line only has one compatible uniformity and is totally bounded and non-complete in it. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1533369/4280 as well. My totally boundedness claim comes from Herllich's book on uniform spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Sorry. I had forgotten that pseudocompact implies totally bounded. Thanks for reminding me.