# Long line with large uncountable ordinals

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, ordinals

The long line, and long ray, is defined with respect to $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal. Is it possible to construct a long line with any of the larger uncountable ordinals, a very long line, if you will?

Would it still be a manifold, if so? From what I've seen, it is generally said that there are only 4 (Hausdorff) 1 dimensional manifolds. The line, circle, long ray and long line. But if a very long line existed, I would assume that it wouldn't be homeomorphic to the long line, since they would have a different cardinality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533139/is-the-long-line-completely-uniformizable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the long line is the longest possible line :). Or rather, you can define a long line $L_\lambda$  for $\lambda>\omega_1$, but it will lack one of the most important properties of the long line itself: *homogeneity*, or more specifically the fact that the (classical) long line "looks locally like $\mathbb{R}$."

The issue is *uncountable cofinality*. The ordinal $\omega_1$ has the property that no countable sequence of countable ordinals has it as a limit (put another way: the countable union of countable sets is countable). This means that if we define the long line $L_\lambda$ of length $\lambda$ for $\lambda>\omega_1$ ($L_\lambda$ consists of $[0, 1)\times\lambda\times 2$ with the appropriate (non-product) topology), then no open neighborhood of the point $p=(0, \omega_1, 1)\in L_\lambda$ is homeomorphic to any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$, hence $L_\lambda$ is not a manifold *(even if we drop the separability requirement)*. More snappily, uncountable cardinals occurring inside a "longer line" break first countability, which is a fundamental property of $\mathbb{R}$.

This is interesting, because it shows that the real obstacle isn't cardinality, but *cofinality*. A big theme in modern set theory is that cofinality is in many ways more fundamental than cardinality. *(Note that there are uncountable ordinals of countable cofinality - $\omega_1+\omega$ is a silly example, and a more interesting one would be the cardinal $\omega_\omega$.)*

Comment: cardinality does play a role in topological properties when your cardinality gets sufficiently large. For instance, if we try to construct a really long line $L_{\lambda} = [0,1)\times \lambda \ such\ that    \left \| \lambda \right \| > \beth_{2}=2^{c}$ then $L_{\lambda}$ will be neither separable nor second countable. So sure we can construct it, but then again topologists may not find it useful or particularly interesting.